# Change Color of Div Dynamically - Javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, html, colors

I think this should be a simple question, but I'm having trouble figuring it out. I have two divs within a parent div and I want to change the color of just the right div (javascript). My code loops through the child divs and then changes the color of both. I can't figure out how to select just the right div and change its color. Here is my code (this changes the color of both):

```
    var color = "#fdd42e";
    var element = document.getElementById(user_id).childNodes;

    for (i=0;i< element.length;i++) {

        if(element[i].id = 'right') {
            element[i].style.background = color;
        }
        else {
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your `i` variable is global which is a very bad thing (imagine calling another function which also loops over i inside that loop). Use `for(var i = 0; ....)` instead

Comment: Why not give the desired div an id or name so you can reference it directly...?

Comment: Name? Bad idea. ID? Good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to select just the right div and change its
>   color.

Use `==` instead of `=`:

```
if(element[i].id = 'right') {
                 ^
            -----|
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple. Thanks!